# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Environment Properties Missing on Scale Up

Tags: spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, tomcat7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Tomcat 7 AWS Elastic Beanstalk application failed to set Environment Properties on new instances that were provisioned as the result of an autoscaling operation.

I created the application via the web UI. I added a custom Environment Property called `DATA_BUCKET`, and deployed my application. It started up fine.

I then used the [Beanstalk Maven Plugin](http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/beanstalk-maven-plugin/) to redeploy my application, and have done so quite a few times. Each time the single starting instance has come up with the correct environment variables set.

I sustained an increased amount of load, and a new instance was provisioned. Sadly the environment properties were not set; or at least they were not visible as System Properties to my Spring MVC application. The code on each instance was identical, but the newly-provisioned instance couldn't resolve the properties.

Would one expect this to work?

Comment: Which solution stack are you using? Can you provide the exact name?

Comment: Afraid not - the environment and application got deleted in an attempt to fix it, hence why I haven't raised an issue on the forums. I'll see if I can dig it out from my Jenkins logs.

Comment: It would be nice if you can dig up the solution stack name of the one that did not work, otherwise can you try with the latest one: 
"64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.3 running Tomcat 7 Java 7"
Do you have the same problem?

Comment: I know it was not the latest one. I think it was "64bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 7".

Comment: I also experienced issues with this solution stack not working with Tomcat 7's RemoteIpFilter, that should make `x-forwarded-by` available as the ServletRequest's getRemoteAddr. Using the latest stack fixed that.